# XML Schema: Constraining Number of Occurrences to be Consistent

Tags: xml, xsd

Say that element B is a child of element A.  Is there a way to make sure that for each A, the number of B elements is unbounded as long as it is consistent across A elements?

For example, the following would validate:

```
    <A>
       <B/>
       <B/>
    </A>
    <A>
       <B/>
       <B/>
    </A>
```

Because both the first and last `<A>` tags have two `<B>` elements.

But the following would not:

```
    <A>
       <B/>
       <B/>
       <B/>
    </A>
    <A>
       <B/>
       <B/>
    </A>
```

Because the first `<A>` element has three `<B>` elements while the second `<A>` element has two `<B>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to accomplish this using just XSD 1.0 due to co-constraints.

> A co-constraint is constraint between two or more values. A co-constraint may exist between elements, or elements and attributes, or attribute and attribute. A co-constraint may exist within a single XML document, or across multiple XML documents. ([Source](http://www.xfront.com/Integrated-schema-approach/Use-Multiple-Schema-Languages.html))

You can check [this article about extending schemas](http://www.xfront.com/ExtendingSchemas.html) for different approaches in overcoming this kind of limitations.

It seems [XSD 1.1 assertions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) will come to the rescue when they become standard.